# How to hyperlink the selected dates in jQuery Datepicker UI?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Can anybody help with this task? I am not a javascript guru and got stuck little bit. I'm using a [**jQuery Datepicker UI**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) to create events calendar.

I want to hyperlink the selected dates (with events names) to appropriate event (separate page or anchor).
Here is the script I'm using to specify my events:

```
$(function() {
    // format: specialDays.year.month.day
    var specialDays = {
        '2011': { 
                '10': { 
                        '1': {content: "Event numer 1", className: "museumevent"},
                        '2': {content: "Event numer 2", className: "museumevent"},
                        '3': {content: "Event numer 3", className: "museumevent"},
                        '4': {content: "Event numer 4", className: "museumevent"},
                        '5': {content: "Event numer 5", className: "museumevent"},
                        '6': {content: "Event numer 6", className: "museumevent"},
                        '7': {content: "Event numer 7", className: "museumevent"},
                        '8': {content: "Event numer 8", className: "museumevent"},
                        '9': {content: "Event numer 9", className: "museumevent"},
                        '10': {content: "Event numer 10", className: "museumevent"},
                        '11': {content: "Event numer 11", className: "museumevent"},
                        '12': {content: "Event numer 12", className: "museumevent"},
                        '13': {content: "Event numer 13", className: "museumevent"},
                        '25': {content: "Event numer 14", className: "museumevent"},
                        '26': {content: "Event numer 15", className: "museumevent"},
                        '27': {content: "Event numer 16", className: "museumevent"},
                        '28': {content: "Event numer 17", className: "museumevent"} }

                }
    }; 

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var d = date.getDate(),
            m = date.getMonth()+1,
            y = date.getFullYear();

        if (specialDays[y] && specialDays[y][m] && specialDays[y][m][d]) {
            var s = specialDays[y][m][d];
            return [true, s.className, s.content]; // selectable

        }
        return [false,'']; // non-selectable


    }});
});
```

Here is the the [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SeU5J/2/) with this calendar.

The main goal is to create custom **Tooltips** for the selected dates (Featured Events) and make these dates **clickable**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using the jQuery UI then I would advise using their modals for your "popup". I have also added some functionality for individualised popups (requested in comment) with a fallback "defauilt".[jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SeU5J/19/)

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<div id="popup" class="popup">
    <p>Default popup</p>
</div>
<div id="popup1"class="popup">
    <p>Popup for event1</p>
</div>
<div id="popup2"class="popup">
    <p>Popup for event1</p>
</div>
```

...

```
var specialDays = {
    '2011': {
        '10': {
            '1': {
                content: "Event numer 1",
                className: "museumevent",
                popupID: "popup1"
            }
```

...

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
        var d = parseInt(dateText.split("/")[1], 10),
            m = parseInt(dateText.split("/")[0], 10),
            y = parseInt(dateText.split("/")[2], 10);

    if ( specialDays[y][m][d].hasOwnProperty("popupID") ) {
        var s = specialDays[y][m][d];
        $('#' + s.popupID).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
    $('#popup').find('.date').text(dateText).end()
        .dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDITED FOR ADDITIONAL REQUESTED FUNCTIONALITY**

Comment: Thanks for that! Works great!
Is there any possibility to make specific popup for each event-date so when I click on different dates I can read different messages (popups)?
Thanks again.

Comment: did you take a look at the addition of custom popups?

Comment: I've just tested it. This is just awesome! Exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {},
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){}
  });
```

You can find the events you need in the Documentation:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-onSelect

also, here is the function for your tooltips:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-beforeShowDay

Comment: Hi. thanks for the reply. I've read this Documentation but my javascript knowledge is limited. I need some examples on how to implement what I need. I think it would be usefull for a lot of people like me just started learning all of this stuff.

Comment: what are you having trouble with in the example i gave you?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do inside of your functions. Inside of the onSelect function dateText is the day that was clicked on. You will have to call other javascript functions from within onSelect to do something with that information.

Comment: I just want to click on the date selected and be hyperlinked to the information (on the same page or separate) for the event that is going to be happen on this date. I don't know how to do this.